# How can I view forums from different sites in a single panel?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

How can I show forums from 4 different WordPress sites in one panel for convenience?

Comment: Using an iframe, or embed, is the first thing that comes to mind

Comment: I don't know much about this subject, can you give detailed information? I have 4 different sites with WordPress infrastructure, the forum plugin that I use independently of each other appears directly in the wordpress admin panel without smtp, but I log in and check 4 different sites every day. It will make my job easier to list the incoming forums in the same place and see them all together. Can I get detailed information on how to handle this?

Comment: I'm talking about information from the forum, that is, from the visitor.

Comment: unfortunately the question has not been solved